# Vuejs + webpack - build for production but deploy to localhost

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Trying to figure out how can I create a production build with webpack but first run it locally as a last test before deploying it to the server.

I was thinking of creating another command something like `npm run build_local` for that purpose but can't quite figure out how to do that.

I can see the following in the root `package.json` and I was thinking of somehow combining `dev` + `build` but can't figure out how to do that (or using config otherwise):

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
```

Any advice on how can I run a production build in localhost with something like `npm run build_local` command?

**EDIT**

What I've tried so far is to run (manually) `http-server ./dist`  which seem to run the folder on localhost, but the result in fact deviates from production (and dev) behavior - in my case it first renders everything as expected but as long as I press refresh, it returns `404 not found` which is unexpected (on dev and server deployed versions it still renders the login page in this case):

for example if I open `localhost:8080`, vue redirects me to `localhost:8080/login` which is expected and works fine. On refresh it gives `404` though.

Ideally I'd expect it to work at least in the same way as dev build on localhost.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you be looking for NPM pre/post hooks?

Comment: @jom, thanks - that might be - I'll try to explore how I can adopt those to make it all work here

Comment: Doesn't `npm run build` create a local folder for you? Something like `dist`?

Comment: @jayarjo yep, exactly. The question is how can I automatically run it on localhost for tests - maybe that's something trivial, but I'm just not an expert at all here so was wondering if someone could point how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was as simple as combining the `dev` command and providing `prod` config to it under the root `package.json`:

```
    "build_local": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.prod.conf.js"
    //
```

Or in the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
    "build_local": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.prod.conf.js"
  }
```

Now I can do `npm run build_local` which runs production build on localhost

**Note**: as per [this github thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/978) and [this doc reference](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) to prevent 404 on refresh also add the following to your `webpack.prod.conf.js` (anywhere in the file, but for reference you can paste it just before `plugins`)

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    historyApiFallback: true, //this line is requried
    compress: true,
    port: 9000
},
```

You can now check your production build under the `localhost:9000`

If anyone knows about any drawbacks give me a comment or post the corrected answer